# The type initializer for 'WindowsApplication1.Module1' threw an exception - please help

Tags: sql-server, vb.net

Please can someone help me. Basically I am using vb.net. All I am doing is `objconn.Close()` and it says

> The type initializer for 'WindowsApplication1.Module1' threw an exception.

and that

> Format of the initialization string does not conform to specification starting at index 25.

I've checked my initalization string several times, it can be seen below:

```
 Public objConn As New SqlConnection("Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename='C:\Users\Sarah\Desktop\Emma's Stuff\Computing\a2\Unit 4\System\WindowsApplication1\WindowsApplication1\SQL db.mdf';Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30;User Instance=True")
```

The file path is right I think so I don't understand what is wrong. I think the format is correct too. Not sure what the index 25 means.

Any help at all is greatly appreciated, been working on this for several hours and it so frustrating not to be able to start it up. Thanks

Comment: @user506912 -- I've reformatted your question, but in the future if you add code tags around your code (the little button with `101 010` on it), it will make things easier to read.

Comment: Oh ok, thanks very much for the help and will do so in future

Comment: My guess would be the single-quote in "Emma's Stuff" is confusing the connection string parser. Try escaping it.

Comment: thank you so much! it worked, you have helped so much!

Comment: @user506912 - don't forget, if you feel an answer solved your problem (now or in the future), be sure to check the green checkbox next to the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm betting the apostrophe in "Emma's Stuff" is breaking the connection string.  You might want to try using double-quotes aruond the path:

```
Public objConn As New SqlConnection("Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=
    ""C:\Users\Sarah\Desktop\Emma's Stuff\Computing\a2\Unit 4\System\
      WindowsApplication1\WindowsApplication1\SQL db.mdf"";
      Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30;User Instance=True")
```

or replacing the single apostrophe in "Emma's Stuff" with two apostrophes:

```
Public objConn As New SqlConnection("Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=
    'C:\Users\Sarah\Desktop\Emma''s Stuff\Computing\a2\Unit 4\System\
     WindowsApplication1\WindowsApplication1\SQL db.mdf';
     Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30;User Instance=True")
```